# Verify that two Python classes have the same API without using `abc`

Tags: python, oop, static-analysis, lint, pylint

I am not a big fan of the `abc` module in Python. If I wanted to write explicit interfaces, I'd use a different language. However, there are some cases when I'd like to verify that, e.g.,

> For each "public" method of class `A`, class `B` has a method with the same name that takes the same number of arguments.

Is there a way to do this? Ideally, it would be some kind of linter step that I can run before executing my program.

Comment: Use something like `mypy` and protocols

Comment: That's an interesting question. Maybe a unit test of some kind...